# Submenu with divs

Tags: css, html

I was wondering if is it possible to create a submenu using divs? All online tutorials use this ul li thing. I don't know how to activate my submenu by hovering over an option. Should I add new class to "director" div? Incuding photos and code pieces.

HTML:

```css
.menu_opcje {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu_wysuwane {
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.menu_wysuwane:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.menu_opcje:hover,
.sidebar_opcje:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_opcje">Strona główna</div>
  <div class="menu_opcje">Galeria</div>
  <div class="menu_opcje">Reżyserzy
    <div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Quentin Tarantino</div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Bracia Coen</div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Wes Anderson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/cldDy.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrvsC.png

Comment: What does "Reżyserowie" mean? I strongly advise to never use non-English css class names. Just makes code so much harder to read for 99% of developers. And yes, ofc it is possible. It is just *unsemantic* and thus, a bad solution.

Comment: I want my submenu to appear when i hover over this tile. It means "directors" in polish ;)

Comment: You have one more closing `</div>` than opening `<div>`s.

Comment: There is this </div> because I copied too much code. I will edit names in a second and edit code :) Sorry for that, Im a real newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is semantically incorrect, though making it appear on hover, do like this

```
.menu_opcje:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.menu_opcje {
  float: left;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu_wysuwane {
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}
.menu_wysuwane:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.menu_opcje:hover,
.sidebar_opcje:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu_opcje:hover div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div class="menu_opcje">Strona główna</div>
  <div class="menu_opcje">Galeria</div>
  <div class="menu_opcje">Reżyserzy
    <div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Quentin Tarantino</div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Bracia Coen</div>
      <div class="menu_wysuwane">Wes Anderson</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```